# Grails 2.5.3 testing service rollback on integration tests with spock

Tags: grails

I have a fairly complex service that creates and saves a lot of domain instances, and because of the logic, I need to create different instances at different times, and in the middle check for certain conditions, that are not only that each instance is valid, but for example I need to check if certain files exist in the file system, etc.

I'm testing the incorrect cases, where the service throws an exception, and I need to test that no instances where persisted if an exception is thrown.

One specific test case was failing, even if the expected exception was thrown, a domain instance was saved to the DB. Then I read that because the integration test was transactional itself, the rollback really occurs at the end of the test, instead of after using the service, so I can check conditions on the "then" section of the spock test case.

So if the rollback occurs after I can test it, I can't test it :(

Then I read that making the integration test not transaction might help, so I added:

static transactional = false

After this, all my other tests started to fail!

My question is: what is the right way of testing services that should rollback when an exception is thrown? I just need to verify that after an exception occurs, there are no alterations to the database (since this is a healthcare application, data consistency is key)

FYI:

This is the service I need to test: https://github.com/ppazos/cabolabs-ehrserver/blob/master/grails-app/services/com/cabolabs/ehrserver/parsers/XmlService.groovy

This is my current test: https://github.com/ppazos/cabolabs-ehrserver/blob/master/test/integration/com/cabolabs/ehrserver/parsers/XmlServiceIntegrationSpec.groovy

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you can modify your code to rely on the framework, then you don't need to test the framework.

Grails uses Spring and the Spring transaction manager rolls back automatically for RuntimeExceptions but not for checked exceptions.  If you throw a RuntimeException for your various validation scenarios then Spring will handle it for you.  If you rely on those facts, your test could then stop at verifying that a RuntimeException is thrown.

If you want to use a checked exception (such as javax.xml.bind.ValidationException ) then you can use an annotation to ensure it causes a rollback:

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = ValidationException.class)
def processCommit( ....
```

and then your test need only check

```
def ex = thrown(ValidationException)
```

See http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-attransactional-settings for more information.